# SharePoint List View - Export to Excel with Formatting and Grouping

Tags: list-view, excel, splist, reports

I have a SPList View with 2 levels of grouping.

First level is Company and the second level is 'Month - Year' which is a calculated field.

Below is the view's screen shot:

[image]

The issue is when a do a 'Export to Excel', I get all the items as the output.

How can I get this view as an Excel sheet.

Maybe, If I can dump this into a GridView and export?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An export to Excel will only ever export the view columns, not the grouping. You will need to build this in Excel from the ground up.

Create a copy of that view. Add the grouping columns as view columns and don't group, then export.

In Excel, build a pivot table. Drag all desired columns into the rows area. Set the pivot table to be a tabular format. Remove the subtotals for all but the Company and the Month column, so these can be collapsed.

Comment: I tried the Pivot table option, I am unable to show the non collapsible columns to show up in a tabular format.

Comment: When I add the Company and Month columns (as collapsible) and another normal column, It works fine. However when I add the second normal column, the first normal column becomes collapsible too with a +/- option at the end of each line item. How can I remove this??

Comment: Ok I manage to strike a deal with the guys who wanted the excel sheet to get rid of the +/- option completely. hence I gave them a sheet where they can use the excel built-in column filter. Thanks a lot :-)!!